# place the image in QFrame

Tags: qt

I want to place the image in QFrame but **the image was drawn by using QPainter** so I have to place that image in QFrame please send me the full code for that

Comment: Show the code you used to draw the image using `QPainter`. Since `QPainter` always draws on some `QPaintDevice`, you should also show what device was that painter operating on. Ideally make a self-contained example

Answer (score 0):

What the image was drawn with doesn't matter: you end up with a `QImage` or a `QPixmap`, and you will want to put it in a `QLabel`, not a `QFrame`. Simply use a `QLabel`, since it *is-a* `QFrame` (and also `QWidget` and `QObject`, of course). There's `QLabel::setPixmap`, and you can easily get a pixmap from a `QImage` :)

Comment: can you explain me with an example please